# Integrate over $t$ if $dr/dt = \sqrt{1 - r^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm stuck on this step trying to solve a math puzzle. How do I integrate this?

Comment: you cannot integrate this directly but need to first ['separate the variables'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables) in order to solve the equation. 
Once you've done that, the integral will be a standard result.

Comment: Stuck on what step? Please make the body of your post self-contained. You don't ask readers of a book to start at the spine; you shouldn't ask readers of your post to start at the subject, which is just an indexing item.

Comment: Please include the question in the question, not just in the title. In any event, it is not clear exactly what integral you are trying to evaluate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that

$$\frac{{dr}}{{dt}} = \sqrt {1 - {r^2}} $$

from where

$$\frac{{dr}}{{\sqrt {1 - {r^2}} }} = dt$$

then integrating

$$\arcsin r + C = t$$

You need a initital value to determine $C$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking to solve a differential equation. This one is separable, so one has
$$
\arcsin(r) = t + C
$$
or 
$$
r = \sin(t + C).
$$